# Не работает JavaScript-код при django

Tags: javascript, python, html, django

JavaScript-код не работает, если подключить его в HTML, который работает в django. Если просто включить HTML, то всё ок, а если через django runserver, то не работает.

```
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>JS</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/media/js/actions.js"></script>
</head>
```

```
alert('test');
```

Как сделать так, чтобы он корректно подключился к HTML-файлу?

Comment: Советую ознакомится с [офф. документацией](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/static-files/).

Comment: а через media нельзя что-ли?

Comment: Ну если в `STATIC_ROOT` и `STATIC_URL` указать `/media` то думаю можно) но зачем?

Comment: Просто я слышал где-то, что говорили, что в продакшене лучше не использовать static, так вот думаю, что использовать

Comment: В продакшене лучше всего `static` и `media` оставить для `nginx` или ему подобных

Comment: А что вместо них использовать тогда?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Причин может быть множество и проблема может не исчезнуть, но путь точно указано неправильно. Для начала следует проверить сделаны ли следующие пункты:

1. {% load static %} - объявлено
2. STATIC_URL = '/static/' - задано

#### Дальше указываем путь в подобном виде:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src={% static "path/to/jquery.min.js" %}></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src={% static "path/to/main.js" %}></script>
```

Также рекомендую подключать скрипты в конце тега `<body>` и почитать о том, как правильно задавить пути к папкам. (Начало пути с "/" - распространенная ошибка)

Comment: Уже давно решена проблема

Comment: @КИТKIT, вот и написал бы ответ когда решил.